# Jboss with Hbase client

Tags: hadoop, jboss, jboss7.x, hbase

at out company, we are facing a problem using HBase client deployed on JBoss server. 
The problem is that JBoss uses Rest Easy as its Rest API. On the other hand HBase client uses Jersey for communication with DataNodes ( Region Servers ). When the application is deployed with the HBase and Jersey lib JBoss complains that only one implementation to JAX-RS must be used. However, if we exclude Jersey HBase starts to throw NullPointerException.

Have anyone ran into these problem or successfully deployed HBase with JBoss ?

Answer (score 0):

Why you are excluding jersey jar. If you are not using resteasy, you can remove reasteasy from JBoss modules. Keep jersey jars.

Comment: for you information this is a known issue.
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RESTEASY-650